# Does FirebaseAuth re-authentication invalidate Firestore subscriptions in Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

This is happening in a Flutter/Firebase app on iOS and Android.

I am seeing problems where my Firestore subscriptions become unresponsive to database changes. It's not clear to me why they work beautifully most of the time and then become stubbornly silent.

I also notice that authentication seems to happen from time to time, as I am listening on the `FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges()` stream. I vaguely recall something about tokens needing to be refreshed which might explain that behavior.

I was wondering if the two things are correlated? Does a re-authentication invalidate Firestore subscriptions?

The subscriptions don't seem to throw an error

```dart
    foo.snapshots().listen(
      () => notAlwaysCalled(), 
      onError: (e) => neverCalled(),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am now seeing execution pathways in my code that can cancel subscriptions in some circumstances.

It now seems to me that my hypothesis was false.

That is to say:

```
There is no invalidation of subscriptions.
```

I will update here if my opinion changes.